# how to count repetitions of first occuring value with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with groups that essentially looks like this

```
DF <- data.frame(state = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B",2), rep("A",2)))

DF
  state
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     B
5     B
6     A
7     A
```

My question is how to count the number of *consecutive* rows where the first value is repeated in its first "block".  So for `DF` above, the result should be 3. The first value can appear any number of times, with other values in between, or it may be the only value appearing. 
The following naive attempt fails in general, as it counts *all* occurrences of the first value.

```
DF %>% mutate(is_first = as.integer(state == first(state))) %>% 
summarize(count = sum(is_first))
```

The result in this case is 5. So, hints on a (preferably) `dplyr` solution to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
rle(as.character(DF$state))$lengths[1]
[1] 3
```

In your `dplyr` chain that would just be:

```
DF %>% summarize(count_first = rle(as.character(state))$lengths[1])

#   count_first
# 1           3
```

Or to be overzealous with piping, using `dplyr` and `magrittr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
DF %>% summarize(count_first = state %>%
                   as.character %>%
                   rle %$%
                   lengths %>%
                   first)

#   count_first
# 1           3
```

Works also for grouped data:

```
DF <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3)),state = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B",2), rep("A",2)))

#   group state
# 1     1     A
# 2     1     A
# 3     1     A
# 4     1     B
# 5     2     B
# 6     2     A
# 7     2     A

DF %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(count_first = rle(as.character(state))$lengths[1])

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    group count_first
#    <dbl>       <int>
#  1     1           3
#  2     2           1
```

Comment: OK, thanks this seems to work. I now need to work out how to apply this to subgroups. Say I have a grouping variable `ID`and want this count for each ID value.

Comment: you're calling `.$state` which is just a vector,so groups aren't handled properly, just use `state` instead so `dplyr` can operate its magic

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! I am afraid I accidentally deleted the comment you refer to here, but I guess I was suggesting  Df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(r = rle(.$state)$lengths[1]),

Answer (score 1):

No need of `dplyr`here but you can modify this example to use it with `dplyr`. The key is the function `rle`

```
state = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B",2), rep("A",2))

x = rle(state)
DF = data.frame(len = x$lengths, state = x$values)
DF

# get the longest run of consecutive "A"
max(DF[DF$state == "A",]$len)
```